# Difference between two periods and three periods in a coffeescript range

Tags: coffeescript

What is the difference between:

```
[a...b]
```

and

```
[a..b]
```

in a coffeescript range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a..b]` generates a range including the upper boundary (inclusive range). So `[1..5]` will evaluate to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

`[a...b]` generates a range excluding the final boundary, so it will generate a range from `a` to `b - 1` (exclusive range), which means `[1...5]` will evaluate to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.